# How to play InputStream with android SoundPool?

Tags: android, soundpool

Sound is not asset, that's why I get it as InputStream:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sound.ogg");
```

How to play java.io.InputStream with android.media.SoundPool?

In class android.media.SoundPool I've found 4 methods to load sound

```
public int load(String path, int priority);
public int load(AssetFileDescriptor afd, int priority);
public int load(Context context, int resId, int priority);
public int load(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length, int priority);
```

but anything works with InputStream.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use InputStream?

Comment: Yes this is requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create AssetFileDescriptor:
`afd = context.getAssets().openFd("sound.ogg");`
And call `load` method: `soundPool.load(afd, 1);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have to use InputStream.

Comment: then you can create new sound file on inner/external storage and after creating, load/play him